# Another question about normal maps

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to bake normal map from high poly object without the existence of a low poly object?

Comment: To what would you apply that normal-map if not to a low-poly object?

Comment: It may be possible if you have **Multires** modifier on high-poly object - then *Bake from Multires* option in **Render** > **Bake** rollout is used. However this doesn't always work (e.g. if high-poly has high polycount not because of **Multires**). See http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Normal_map for more info

Comment: @tkausl To the same object but without subdivision modifier, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You just need to ensure that you have an image texture assigned to the object and that the object has a UV map.

In it's simplest form, using Cycles:

1. Split your screen so you can see the 3D view and a UV/Image
   Editor
2. Create a new image in the image editor.  Let's call it
   "BakedNormalMap"
3. Switch back to your 3D view and select your hi-poly object
4. Make sure you've unwrapped it and it has a UV map.
5. Add a new material
6. Click the dot at the end of the Color option and choose Image
   Texture (this can be achieved with the node editor if you prefer)
7. Select your BakedNormalMap as the image
8. Switch from the Materials tab to the Render tab and scroll to the
   bottom to find the Bake options
9. Choose the Normal option and below this in the "Normal Settings" choose Space: Object
10. Bake

Don't forget to save your file.

Comment: ...And what result after baking did you get using this method ? What colors does image have after being baked ?

Comment: @MrZak You can bake object space normal map like this and then apply it to whatever other mesh you like. This should though be stated in the asnwer, as it is it's misleading.

Comment: @Jerryno you mean object space instead of tangent space (as by default) ?

Comment: @MrZak yep, exactly

Comment: Apologies.  I missed that in my description.  Under the Bake options when you switch to a Bake type of "Normal" there are the extra parameters for Normal Settings.  As pointed out by @Jerryno, the Space should be set to Object.